# Part of my Ubuntu 23.04 screen is not working, but it's working well in Windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, graphics, screen, 23.04, windows-11

I have a dual boot system with Windows 11, and Ubuntu 23.04. Part of my screen is not working, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: That particular part of my screen is not working]